# Generate random number in [7000000000, 9999999999]

Tags: c++, random

I am new to c++, and i am writing a program for generating random phone number. But the program is giving same random number. 
I have also used

```
srand (time (null));
```

and

```
srand (time (0));
```

My code is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int randomno (int array [], int size)
{

    array [0]=rand()%3+7;
    for (int i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
        array [i]=rand()%10;
    }
    int phoneno=array[size];
    return phoneno;
}
int main ()
{
    srand (time (NULL));
    int no[10];
    cout << "Random phone no is " << randomno (no, 10);
}
```

This program should show numbers in the format (9 or 8 or 7 then 9 more digits).
The program below runs well and will give you an idea what i want to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    srand (time (NULL));
    cout << "The Random phone No. is ";
    int d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10;
    d1=rand()%3+7;
    d2=rand()%10;
    d3=rand()%10;
    d4=rand()%10;
    d5=rand()%10;
    d6=rand()%10;
    d7=rand()%10;
    d8=rand()%10;
    d9=rand()%10;
    d10=rand()%10;
    cout << d1<<d2<<d3<<d4<<d5<<d6<<d7<<d8<<d9<<d10;
}
```

But later i decided to use Arrays and functions.

Help me out.

Answer (score 2):

`array[size]` is out-of-range, so you must not access (read nor write) it.

You will have to print each elements separately to get what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void randomno (int array [], int size)
{

    array [0]=rand()%3+7;
    for (int i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
        array [i]=rand()%10;
    }
}
int main ()
{
    srand (time (NULL));
    int no[10];
    randomno (no, 10);
    cout << "Random phone no is ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) cout << no[i];
}
```

Comment: "*You will have to print each elements separately to get what you want.*" No, he can use `long`.

Comment: @lllllllllll `long` may be insufficient and is insufficient if it is 32-bit long for storing 10-digit decimal number. Using `int64_t` is good.

Answer (score 2):

Your issues are below:

`int randomno(...){...}`

should be

`long long randomno(...){...}`

---

`int phoneno=array[size];`

should be

```
long long phoneno = array[9]; // you cannot do it for generic size of array because long has its boundaries
long long temp = 10; 
for( int i = 1; i < 10; ++i )
{ 
     phoneno += (array[9 - i] * temp ); 
     temp *= 10; 
}
```

---

Below you may find my attempt how to solve the problem using `c++11 <random>`

```
#include<random>
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_set>

int main()
{
    unsigned number_of_numbers = 10;

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen( rd() );  // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis( -1000000000,
                                          1999999999 );
    std::unordered_set< long long > numbers;

    while( numbers.size() != number_of_numbers )
        numbers.insert( dis( gen ) + 8000000000 );

    for( auto & i : numbers )
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

produces

```
9787794699
7356007215
8081593821
7780007650
9167309970
7172218239
8124995716
7281138623
7185218656
8615788448
```

Comment: `<unordered_set>` or `<set>` is needed to make sure that all generated numbers are unique.

Comment: On windows, long is the same as int. If you want to have portable 64 bit numbers you should use (u)int64_t or long long.

Comment: @MikeMB I stay with fundamental types (`long long`). Thanks Microsoft once again; Unix 4ever.

Comment: Fair enough. Personally, I like to be explicit about the size for anything but `int` and `size_t`, but I'm also doing a lot of programming on embedded systems.

Answer (score 0):

The function `randomno` takes an array of `int`s; it sets all of their values appropriately, then returns `array[size]`, which is off the end of the array. At best this will produce an unpredictable value. Get rid of the return statement, and in `main` look at the ten values that were set by the function.

Comment: @MikeCAT that helped. I would like to ask that why was my question downvoted as I am new to stacksoverflow and c++ too ( I have not even started in colleges).

Answer (score 0):

The array in int phoneno=array[size] is never set - you assigning values for array positions 0 .. (size-1) as the for condition is i

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
int randomno (int array [], int size) {
    array [0]=rand()%3+7;
    for (int i=1; i<size; i++) { array [i]=rand()%10; }
    int phoneno=array[size];
    return phoneno;
}
```

has two problems. You cannot copy arrays like that `int phoneno=array[size];` and you cannot return arrays from functions. `return phoneno` returns a garbage value that is pretty useless and has little to do with the random values you put into the array.

I would suggest you to use a vector:

```
std::vector<int> randomno (int size) {
    std::vector<int> result;
    result.push_back(rand()%3+7);
    for (int i=1; i<size; i++) { result.push_back(rand()%10); }
    return return result;
}
```

and then print it like this:

```
std::vector<int> phoneno = randomno(10);
for (auto i : phoneno) { std::cout << i; }
std::cout << std::endl;
```

However, as others pointed out in their answers, if you want random numbers you should take a look at the rngs in `<random>` as `rand()` has serious problems and should not be used once you need good quality random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it much more simply than this:

```
return (long long)(rand()*((long long)9999999999L-7000000000L+1)+7000000000L);
```

E&OE

Comment: Did you test what you suggested?